# Program does nothing on first input of user (skips whole code in program)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void broj_na_artikli(int &artikli);
bool is_num(const string &s);

int main()
{
    int artikli;
    broj_na_artikli(artikli);
    for(int i = 0; i < artikli; i++)
        cout << i << endl;
}

void broj_na_artikli(int &artikli){
    while(true){
        string vlez;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> vlez;

        if(is_num(vlez)){
            artikli = atoi(vlez.c_str());
            if(artikli > 100 || artikli < 1){
                cout << "Error, try again." << endl;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "Error, try again." << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool is_num(const string &s){
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while(it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)){
        ++it;
    }
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

Whatever you input as a first result, it doesn't react to the input, the program literally skips the whole code and then goes back to the beginning and asks for another input again. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `cin.ignore()` "[Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including delim](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Blocks until you enter a '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/
std::stream::ignore wait for numeric_limits::max() or '\n'.

Best Regards,

Michel.