# After input my program seems to skip the first IF statement and go directly to ELSE

Tags: c++, windows

I have a problem with the code. It compiles with no errors, but right after taking input from the user it even with correct values it seems to skip the first conditional statement and go directly to ELSE which causes the program to terminate. I can't seem to find the cause for this behavior.

I think it might the issue with the way the conditional statement is constructed: 
`if( ((S <= 25 && S <= 75) % 5 == 0) && (U < 0.2 && U < 0.7) ){`

I need to check if the value entered is `25 <= S <= 75` and is divisible by 5, as well as the other value being `0.2 < U < 0.7`

[Course Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAxbE.jpg)

```
//#include "stdafx.h" // Header File used VS.
#include <iostream>
//#include <iomanip> // Used to format the output.
#include <cstdlib> // Used for system().
#include <math.h> // Used for sqrt().
using namespace std;// ?


int main (){

    int S; // Gram/Litre
    double U; // Specific Max. Growth Rate. Per Hour.
    double D; // Maximum Dilution Rate.
    const int K = rand() % 7 + 2; // Saturation Constant - Randomly Gegerated Number Between 2 & 7. In Hour/Litre.

    cout << "Enter value between 25 and 75, divisible by 5, for S in Gram/Litre: ";
    cin >> S;
    cout << "Enter value bigger than 0.2, but less than 0.7, for U per Hour: ";
    cin >> U;

    if( ((S <= 25 && S <= 75) % 5 == 0) && (U < 0.2 && U < 0.7) ){ // Check Condition ***May Need Adjustments***

        D = U * ( 1 - sqrt ( K / ( K + S) ) ); // Might have to adjust values to fit data type double. Add .00
        cout.precision(3); // Prints 3 values after decimal point.
        cout << "Maximum dilution rate is: " << D << endl;

        if( D < 0.35 && D < 0.45 ){
            cout << "Kinetic parameters are acceptable." << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Kinetic  parameters are not acceptable." << endl;
        }

    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid Input. Program will now terminate." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE"); // Pauses the program before termination.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `cin` isn't being cleared correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20913785/477563

Comment: `S <= 25` does not match your description. Also you check if the result of `(S <= 25 && S <= 75)` is divisible by 5 instead of `S` itself.

Maybe you want to split your condition and store the values of the different parts into temporaries like `bool isSInRange=(25 <= S && S <= 75);` first.

Comment: Guys one more question, when I print out variable `D` is seems to print out value of `U` instead. I don't see any issues with math                       ` D = U * ( 1 - sqrt ( K / ( K + S) ) );'
`cout.precision(3);`
`cout << "Maximum dilution rate is: " << D << endl;'                           What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want 25 <= S <= 75, you should have
`25 <= S && S <= 75`, not `S <= 25 && S <= 75`. Same with `U < 0.2` and `D < 0.35` - they should be `0.2 < U` and `0.35 < D`.

Second, the above statement returns a boolean - thus, if S is a value between 25 and 75, the boolean will be cast to an integer value of 1, and `1 % 5 == 0` always be false. (Similarly, if S is outside this range, the boolean will be cast to an integer 0 and `0 % 5 == 0` will always be true)

A correct, complete if-statement is as follows:

`if((25 <= S && S <= 75) && (S % 5 == 0) && (0.2 < U && U < 0.7)){
    ...
    if(0.35 < D && D < 0.45){
        ...
    }
    ...
}`

Comment: Agreed. However, there are (lot of (unneeded parentheses)). `if (25 <= S && S <= 75 && S % 5 == 0 && 0.2 < U && U < 0.7)` means the same thing and is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a number between 25 and 75 from the input, the `if( ((S <= 25` is always false.

You must use `if( ((S >= 25 && ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem mainly lies in your loop conditions. For example, in this line from your code:

```
    if( ((S <= 25 && S <= 75) % 5 == 0) && (U < 0.2 && U < 0.7) ){ 
        //...
    }
```

The if condition **S <= 25 && S <= 75** simply can be rewritten as *S <= 25* because in words, your parameter states that if S is less than or equal to 25 OR if S is less than or equal to 75, and so on.

The same problem exists here: **U < 0.2 && U < 0.7**. Once again, the if statement simply checks whether U is less than 0.2 and U is less than 0.7, the latter always being true if the former is true.

However, in your output statement before accepting the 2 inputs, you state that S should have a range of 25 <= S <= 75, meaning that S is *greater* than 25; not less. The same issue for U: you are expecting input ranging between 0.2 < U < 0.7.

How you should rewrite your if-then statement is as follows:

```
    if( (S >= 25 && S <= 75) && (S % 5 == 0) && (U > 0.2 && U < 0.7) ){ 
        //...
    }
```

This not only makes your if-statement's conditions easier to read and comprehend, but it also eliminates the errors. This should work now. The meaning of the code stays the same: *S* has to be between 25 and 75 (including these numbers), it should be divisible by 5, and U should be between 0.2 and 0.7.

BTW, the same mistake exists in this part of your code also:

```
    if( D < 0.35 && D < 0.45 ){...
```

I fixed it below:

```
    if( D > 0.35 && D < 0.45 ){...
```

Good luck!